# The other (one)

Tags: pronouns, determiners

Page 55 of A Practical English Grammar reads

> Normally, *other(s)* is only used alone if it refers to a noun that has
> been mentioned before. An exception is the common plural use of (*the)
> others* to mean *(the) other people*, but not **on the phone you can't see the other.*

Would adding *one*, *...you can't see the other **one***, solve this supposed ungrammaticality?

OED: [*One son went to live in Australia and the other **one** was killed in a car crash*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/other?q=other)

Comment: I would prefer _...the other **person**._

Comment: Other one is not always a person, either. Only if it refers to a category of person.

Comment: You don't *always* have to explicitly include the relevant noun when singular "the other" refers to a person. *We still sometimes chat on a landline phone, but obviously then neither of us can see **the other** [one].*

Comment: Is _*on the phone you can't see the other_ actually ungrammatical?

Comment: You wouldn't say, "On the phone, one can't see the others." You would say, "On the phone one can't see others." That means the singular equivalent isn't, "On the phone one can't see *the* other," albeit that's not ungrammatical. Rather, the equivalent would be, "On the phone you can't see *an* other," but in English, "an other" is contracted into the single word "another," so the equivalent actually is, "On the phone one can't see another," which isn't ungrammatical, either.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman that very same page marks as ungrammatical the example *_He never listens to another._

Comment: You quote selectively. 'One son went to live in Australia and the other one was killed in a car crash' sounds logical; a bare 'The other one was killed in a car crash' sounds ludicrous. It's not a matter of grammaticality. 'When using a [traditional!] phone, you can't see the other person' is fine, with an understood and acceptable deletion of 'involved in the phone call', but not '... the other' / '... the others'. There is under-specification.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OTHER (noun) 
 the other one: 
_Each praises **the other**_ https://www.wordreference.com/definition/other

Comment: But here also specification is provided by 'each'. 'Other' and 'other person' are of course synonymous as NPs, but not totally interchangeable. 'The other's grass is always greener' would sound at best pretentious.

Answer (score 0):

> Would adding *one*, *...you can't see the other **one***, solve this supposed ungrammaticality?

Yes. This is, of course, why the book states that this rule applies only when *other* is *used alone,* i.e. as a noun rather than an adjective.